# Postgresql: manage users permissions with groups

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I`m trying to manage users permissions using groups (roles), but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
What I want to do is something like this:

```sql
CREATE ROLE readonly_role;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly_role;

CREATE USER my_user IN ROLE readonly_role;
```

With this I'd like to grant only select permissions to my_user, but when I check on the roles created, readonly_role does have only select permissions, but my_user has been created with all default permissions.

I'm using postgresql 15.

Answer (score 0):

Your commands will work and grant `my_user` the `SELECT` privilege on all tables. The user has the default permissions, but inherits the privileges from `readonly_role`.

What you have forgotten, particularly in v15 where the privileges on schema `public` have changed, is to grant the `USAGE` privilege on that schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly_role;
```

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL 15, use ALTER USER with SET ROLE to assign the user the role in order to control user permissions through groups (roles). Here is the code which I updated, in this code My_user inherits the readonly_role permissions and only has SELECT access to tables in the public schema;

```
-- Create a readonly role and grant SELECT on all tables in the public schema
CREATE ROLE readonly_role;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly_role;

-- Create a user and set their role to readonly_role
CREATE USER my_user;
ALTER USER my_user SET ROLE readonly_role;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Tha `ALTER USER` is not necessary.